# Associating a given django model with it's corresponding create/edit form

Tags: django, django-forms

**tl;dr**: I'm looking for an easy way of associating a model's form with a given model, such that knowing only the model I can render the appropriate create/edit form.  I've developed a solution by storing the corresponding `ModelForm`'s name as a string attribute on the Model class, but being new to django, am curious if this is the preferred solution.

---

I'm working on django task/project management site which will store tasks for a number of product groups. Navigating to `mysite/<ProductGroup>/create_task.html` should direct the user to a form for creating a task/project within that product group. By default, this will allow editing of a base `Task` model instance using a simple `ModelForm`.  However, for specific product groups I'd like to have the option of subclassing the `Task` model (example `SalesTask`) and displaying a `ModeForm` specific for that subclass (eg `SalesTaskForm`).

My current solution is to store the task-object-type as a contentype in the `ProductGroup` model, eg:

```
class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    task_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    ...
    <define other fields here>
```

Then define a base Task model with a special string attribute giving the corresponding `ModelForm` to use when rendering, eg:

```
<models.py>
class Task(models.Model):
    product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductGroup)
    ...
    <define task fields common to all Task subclasses>
    ...
    # Associate model with a form (regular python class attribute, 
    # not a django field)
    form = 'TaskForm'

<forms.py>
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task

*Note that it would be slightly more convenient if I could set Task.form equal 
to the actual TaskForm(ModelForm) class rather than a string, but I couldn't 
get around the circular imports when trying this route (models.py `Task` 
would need to import `Taskorm` from forms.py, which itself needs to import 
`Task`).*
```

This setup allows me to easily extend the Task model for a given product group by simply subclassing `Task` and `TaskForm`, overriding the `Task.form` attribute on the model subclass definition (eg `SalesTask.form = 'SalesTaskForm'`) and then set the task_type foreign key for the sales instance of `ProductGroup`.

The resulting `create_task` view function can then intelligently render the appropriate form for a given product group:

```
<views.py>
...
import mysite.forms as taskforms
...
def create_task(request, name):
    try:
        product_group = ProductGroup.object.get(product_group_iexact=name)
    except ProductGroup.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_model = product_group.item_type.model_class()
    try:
        form = taskforms.__getattribute__(task_model.form)
    except AttributeError:
        raise Http404

    if form.is_valid():
        # Process form
    ...
```

This seems to work and I'm not unhappy with the solution, but it seems like a common need to associate a form with a given model and--being relatively new to django--I'm wondering if there's a built-in or more eloquent method of dealing with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why make form so compicated: form = taskforms.__getattribute__(task_model.form)? As I understand you construct a form with a certain type on this line.

Comment: @sergzach Not sure I follow (though I'm definitely interested if there's a simpler way I'm missing).  To make sure were on the same page: `task_model.form` is the string stored in a `Task` model (or subclass thereof) that let's me know what form to use for a given subclass of `Task`.  To make the view generic for all subclasses of the `Task` model I need this line to load the appropriate form type.

Comment: The traditional way is to create a separate form for each model. It's not a problem with DRY, conceptually it's an input extention for it's model. When you create a new form you assign it to a model. Model shouldn't contain any reference to it's form, it's a violation of encapsulation for Django. Models don't know about their forms.

Comment: @sergzach I see your point.  In reality all subclasses of the `Task` model will their own form (to display their additional fields).  For most product groups the base `Task` model and `TaskForm` will suffice. But I'd like to avoid special casing my view function to show the appropriate form for all product groups using a subclass of the `Task`.  I suppose what I'm trying to do might be non-standard, so might not have any built-in method. Personally I feel this implementation would be easier for me to maintain, but perhaps I'm setting myself up for unanticipated issues down the road?

Comment: Yes, there are unanticipated issues if your code becomes more difficult. If you go the road you should be ready to solve easy standart tasks with not standart methods. I think it's a time to remind a basic python rule: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.". Why didn't you think to implement your views as classes and apply class inheritance to avoid repeated lines? You could think of something that is very compact but doesn't break the rules.

Comment: @sergzach Thanks, your comments pointed me in the right direction.  As a beginner its pretty easy to confuse clever with naive (though you can probably assume it's the latter).  My question was geared at discovering if I was going about this the right way or not, and based on your comments I can conclude my original solution was wrong.  See my answer below for what I hope is a more standard approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on sergzach's comments I realized I should abandon my current solution and switch to class-based generic views instead.  I couldn't find much documentation regarding the built-in class based views (beyond the simple `TemplateView` example), but digging into the source of `django.views.gereic.edit` reveals the `CreateView` view class, which provides quite an eloquent solution.

If one wants to specify the `template_name` and `model` as arguments in your url.conf, you can import and use `CreateView` directly.  For my case, I still wanted to grab the product_group from the url's regex, and then use the `ContentType` field on the given product group to grab the appropriate model.  So my `ProductGroup` class definition remains the same as above and my url.py becomes:

```
from mysite.views import CreateTask
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^product_groups/(?P<product_group>[\w-]+)/new_task$', 
        CreateTask.as_view(),
        name='create_task'),
    ...
```

And then in views.py I simply subclass `CreateView` and override it's `get_form_class` method to grab the appropriate model from the captured product group:

```
class CreateTask(CreateView):
    template_name = "item_form.html"
    def get_form_class(self):
        """
        Returns the form class to use in this view
        """
        if self.form_class:
        # If we pass form_class as an arg, use that
                return self.form_class
        if self.kwargs['product_group']:
        # Otherwise, get the product_group from the url regex, get its associated
        # task model subclass and have the form_facory generate a form_class
            try:
                product_group = ProductGroup.objects.get(product_group__iexact=
                        self.kwargs['product_group'])
            except ProductGroup.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
            model = product_group.task_type.model_class()
        # The remainder is straight from CreateView's definition:
        else:
                if self.model is not None:
                    # If a model has been explicitly provided, use it
                    model = self.model
                elif hasattr(self, 'object') and self.object is not None:
                    # If this view is operating on a single object, use
                    # the class of that object
                    model = self.object.__class__
                else:
                    # Try to get a queryset and extract the model class
                    # from that
                    model = self.get_queryset().model
        return model_forms.modelform_factory(model)
```

A really slick feature of the `CreateView` class (or any other class inheriting from `ModelFormMixin`) is that if a model's corresponding `ModelForm` hasn't been created or provided as an argument, the `ModelFormMixin` will automatically generate a generic `ModelForm` using the `model_form_factory`.  As such, if I don't want any customizations I don't even have to create a corresponding model form.  So, if say the Sales group wants an additional field `budget` included, I can simply subclass the base `Task` model as `SalesTask`, add the `budget` field to this subclass, and then set the `task_type` foreign key to point to `SalesTask` instead of `Task`.  Very slick!

Comment: You can create your custom classes not using view classes of Django. In some cases it is more convenient solution. Implement as_view function with decorator @classmethod. In as_view method you can construct your class and then assign it to self:  def as_view( cls ): \ self = cls() \ return self.view. Then you can use the function as_view in urls.py: url( r'^$', MyView.as_view() ),

Comment: The full example of the base class without excesses: class View( object ): \
 @classmethod \
 def as_view( cls ): \
  self = cls() \
  return self.pre_view \

 def pre_view( self, request, *args, **kwargs ): \
  return self.view( request, *args, **kwargs ) \
 
 def view( self, request ): \
  raise EmptyViewException() \

 def _redirect( self, page ): \
  return redirect( page ) \

 def raise404( self ): \
  raise Http404 \